# NU3005: The package signature file entry is invalid. The central directory header field 'compression method' has an invalid value (8)

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-assembly

I have tried to sign a non-signed NuGet package ([ServiceWire](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceWire/#readme-body-tab)) and publish it in our internal feed, however i get the following error while dotnet restore

> NU3005: The package signature file entry is invalid. The central
> directory header field 'compression method' has an invalid value (8).

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3005) says that i should contact the owner to sign the package, however i do not think this is possible.